# Where does YCSB HBase store data and how can I access it?

Tags: hbase, ycsb

I'm trying to benchmark HBase using [YCSB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB). I ran it for hbase. When I went to hbase shell and checked the `list` of tables, I couldn't see any new tables having been created. So, where does YCSB create tables and how do I see the content of them?

Comment: To try and help you find answers I have changed the title of your question so people reading it can tell what exactly you want to know. A  general question like "how does HBase work" sounds too broad and difficult to answer, but what you want to know is something I would expect other people in the field to know. I hope this helps you find an answer!

Answer (score 0):

YCSB does not create the tables. The client needs to create the table before running YCSB.

Please refer the link [here](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Running-a-Workload#step-1-set-up-the-database-system-to-test).

Comment: got it! But when I ran the code, it doesn't throw any exception. So, can you share more info on it? I mean, the create command and other details I need to run the process.

Comment: I've created table using `create 'usertable',{NAME=>'f1'}` and ran the ycsb tool again. But I don't see any data in the table :|